# How can I convert a string (of one character) to character in squeak?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

How can I convert a string (of one character) to character ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really have to *convert* it, but *get* it.

In Smalltalk, a `String` is a `Collection` of characters.

As for every collection, sending the `first` method will give you it's first component - the first `Character`. If you have a single-character String, that would get you that *single* Character.

You can send it the `at:` message, too, with a given index. `'Test' at: 2` would give you the `$e` - Collections are 1-based, at least on the Pharo version I'm testing on :)